# How to show message if neither is selected?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a radio where a user chooses 'YES'/'NO'.
  Right now if a user selects NO the field wont be required only Yes is selected.
  If NO is selected then reaseon_text should not be required, only when additional_fte equals YES. 
  How do I get it if neither is select to show the message and if additional_fte is seleted 'Yes' to make reasoeon_text required ?

With the code below it make the additional_fte  required.

```
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="additional_fte"> Yes 
<input type="radio" value="No"  name="additional_fte" > No
<textarea class="spellcheck_textarea" name="reaseon_text" ></textarea>

      var validator = $('#commentForm').validate({
                    rules: {
                       additional_fte: {
                        required:  true

                      },
                       reaseon_text: {
                        required: true
                      },

                    },
                    messages: {},


                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                     ...
                  });


                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#commentForm').validate({
    rules: {
        additional_fte: {
            required: required: true  // <- invalid syntax, 'required' repeated.
            ....
```

`required: required: true` is invalid syntax.  Just use `required: true` instead.

**Otherwise working:  http://jsfiddle.net/kp633gex/**

---

**EDIT**:

> How do I get it if neither is select to show the message and if `additional_fte` is seleted 'Yes' to make `reasoeon_text` required?

Using [the `depends` property](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#rules) on the `required` rule, check the value of the radio buttons...

```
reaseon_text: {
    required: {
        depends: function(element) {
            return ($('input[name="additional_fte"]:checked').val() === 'Yes');
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/kp633gex/1/**

Comment: oops sorry that was my mistake of repeating it, edit question